# zend framework 1.11 cannot access phpthumb library

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am working on a zend framework 1.11 site and using phpthumb for thumbnail. All of a sudden it application saying

```
Warning: include_once() [function.include-once]: Unable to access /var/www/vhosts`/ege.org/httpdocs/application/library/PhpThumb/ThumbLib.inc.php in /var/www/vhosts/ege.org/httpdocs/application/controllers/PageController.php on line 95`
```

The page Controller line 95 is

```
 include_once '../library/PhpThumb/ThumbLib.inc.php';
```

The application was working fine. Now this problem occured all of a sudden.
Note: This works in my windows devlopment server but not in production linux server

Comment: This can't appear magically. What have you changed?

Comment: As the warning suggest the file path to the phpThumb is wrong. So this  cuold mean that some changes have to your include path(s).

Comment: See where you are and what you are trying to includ!!

Comment: it doesn't access that file no matter what i do ../ or ../../ or ever APPLICATION_PATH.'/../'Is there any other better way pls help

Comment: This works in my windows devlopment server but not in production linux server

Comment: Might have to do with Linux being case sensitive. That's why it can work in Windows but not in Linux with the same code. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-rules-for-naming-file-and-directory-names/

Answer (score 0):

In the classic zend app that will work:

```
include_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/library/PhpThumb/ThumbLib.inc.php';
```

Remeber that linux system is case sensitive.